# Tcp window size won't go above 130048

Tags: linux-networking, tcp, buffer

I have 2 servers set up with about 80ms latency between them.  Both are centos 6 and run a java app that transfers data from on location to another.  Both are on 1gbps connections.

I have been trying different sysctl settings and different send & receive buffer settings in java but no matter what I set them to, I cannot get the tcp window size to go above 130048 in the tcp dumps.  This equates to roughly 13mbps which is the actual throughput I am getting.

Current sysctl settings are:

```
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_default = 2400000
net.core.rmem_default = 2400000
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096    65536 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096    87380 16777216
```

Comment: Can you show your `sysctl.conf` settings?

Comment: Sure, `net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_default = 2400000
net.core.rmem_default = 2400000

net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
`

Comment: 1Gbps at 80ms gives a Bandwidth Delay Product of just under 10Mb. Try increasing your socket buffers? `4096 10485760 33554432`